# What statistical test to use for testing means of normalised data against control?

Tags: anova, dataset, normalization

I'm studying the electrophysiological response of mosquitoes towards different odours at different concentrations. Because the set-up and the environment gives so much noise, I have to normalise my data to a control odour. Now I want to know if the normalised means of my tested odours at different concentrations differ from the control, i.e. do the mosquitoes respond differently towards the odours than they do to the control?

I thought I could do a one-way t-test, and compare the mean of each odour and concentration to 0. However, then I'm not taking into account that there are several odours and concentrations, so a ANOVA with my control set to 0 seems to be more appropriate, but doesn't seem like a good way either. How should I approach this?

I hope I've explained it clearly. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are exposing the same mosquitoes to multiple stimuli then your data is not independent and you will have to account for that in the analysis. One way to do this is with a mixed model.

If you are using different mosquitoes each time, then it seems like an ANOVA problem, but I don't know what you mean by "control set to 0" nor why it "doesn't seem like a good way".  Can you  elucidate?

Comment: The same mosquito is indeed exposed to multiple stimuli, but every single compounds is tested only once on one mosquito. And I've done this for several mosquitoes of course.

Comment: Then you need a mixed model (aka multilevel model) or another method for dealing with dependent data.

Comment: Since my data is normalised to the control (response of compound-response control), I thought the control then becomes 0. If you then want to know it the compounds differ response from the control, I thought an ANOVA could be used with multiple comparison post hoc, to see if the compounds differ from 0?